# Left offset difference in chrome on absolute vs relative positioned images in parent being uneven amount of pixels wide

Tags: css, google-chrome, positioning

I have a div with a width of 49% (as part of a responsive layout). In this div I have two images stacked on top of each other, one positioned relative and one positioned absolute. They are both centered in the parent - the relative one using `margin: 0 auto;` and the absolute one using `margin:0 auto; left:0; right:0;`.

Now, Chrome sometimes (depending on window width) creates an offset difference of a pixel or two between the absolute and the relative image. This can be seen in [my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/P4AfQ/) when inspecting the image elements - if you can't see a difference in Chrome, try resizing the window somewhat.

I'm getting this difference in Chrome 21 for Windows. It's not present in Firefox or IE, so I wonder if is this a known bug in Chrome, and is there a fix?

**Update:** It does not seem to be a result of the percentage width of the parent, but rather it appears whenever the parent is an uneven amount of pixels wide, see [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/P4AfQ/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its really Interesting you have position both to be same logically by using

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    width: 215px;
}
.relative-img {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.absolute-img {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

But actually when try to get the left position of both the image there is **difference in the left position of .5px**

```
relative-img - 65.5 
absolute-img - 66
```

see Console of [this](http://jsbin.com/ogicun/2/edit)

Also I tried to make them Same by assigning absolute

```
$(".relative-img").offset().left =$(".absolute-img").offset().left;
```

But still the result is same

```
relative-img - 65.5 
absolute-img - 66
```

**Surprised ?**

**Answer to this is may be In the Fact that :** In Chrome the value fractional part is truncated, so 65, 65.5 and 65.6 all show the same result  Nice demo by [Skilldrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49376/skilldrick) is [hear](http://jsfiddle.net/q5BQs/3/)

Comment: Seems like you're on to something there. I don't get why there would be a difference between absolute and relative positioning though. Will look into this further.